# Should I use set_value() to repopulate a form in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

My question is whether I should use set_value() at all to re-populate a form.  It might seem odd to say that, however I am creating a shared controller function and view which can be used to either add a new record or edit an existing one.  It seems to make sense to do this since the functionality is so incredibly alike.

As such, if we call up an existing record to edit I do this:

```
$data['fields'] = $this->customer_model->get_customer($id);
```

If the form is submitted to save the record, or if we're adding a record for the first time, the form has the potential to reload if the user makes a mistake so I populate $data['fields'] this way instead:

```
$data['fields'] = array(
    'company' => $this->input->post('company') ?: '',
    'website' => $this->input->post('website') ?: '',
    'credit_limit' => $this->input->post('credit_limit') ?: ''
);
```

My form element looks like this:

```
<input type="text" name="company" value="<?php echo set_value('company', $fields['company']); ?>"  />
```

But I'm thinking it may as well look like this:

```
<input type="text" name="company" value="<?php echo escape_html($fields['company']); ?>"  />
```

Since the form data could come from either user input (when adding or saving) or from the database (when retrieving a record to edit) I cannot rely entirely on `post()` or `set_value()` without the 2nd parameter.  Furthermore, the second parameter for set_value() will always exist (`$fields['company']` in this example) because it's initialized from the start, which is why I am thinking of just using it directly.

Is there a problem with this approach?

Comment: I don't think there is a problem with that approach, I use the same approach in most of my projects...I do not know if there is any 'rule' against it either...

Comment: The only advantage of using the set_value() form helper function is to  `simplify setting the value` of an already submitted value for the purpose of re-displaying it

Comment: Personally, I prefer using the form helper set_value() since you want to use the same form for adding new records and editing existing ones. Also, there is really no big reason to use escape_html() when the submitted values will still be passed through the codeIgniter  form_validation() preset rules at the server side.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to populate form fields on FALSE return of Form Validation or insert data for editing operations, I suggest you to use following helper:

**Usage**

```
<input type="text" name="last_name" value="<?=vset_value('last_name','',$rs);?>">
```

**Explanation**

`$rs` here is the $db data for record (if you are sending it to view). To stay at the safe side please include `$this->data['rs'] = false;` at your controller. If `$rs` is set and true, helper take results from it and display it. Otherwise it displays if the key exist in `$_POST`. If both don't exists, it display default value.

**Helper**

```
/**
 * vayes_helper::vset_value
 *
 * Retains state of INPUT text after Form Validation
 *
 * @access  public
 * @param string  name of INPUT tag
 * @param string  default value for INPUT tag
 * @param mixed   DB Result (array or object)
 * @return  string
 */
if(!function_exists('vset_value')) {
  function vset_value ($name_of_input,$default_state='',$db_result_array='') {
    $CI = &get_instance();
    $render_state = $default_state;
    if($CI->input->post()) {
      $render_state = $CI->input->post($name_of_input);
    } else {
      if(is_object($db_result_array) && isset($db_result_array->$name_of_input)) {
        $render_state = (isset($db_result_array->$name_of_input)) ? $db_result_array->$name_of_input : $default_state;
      } else if($db_result_array != '' && array_key_exists($name_of_input,$db_result_array)) {
        $render_state = (isset($db_result_array[$name_of_input])) ? $db_result_array[$name_of_input] : $default_state;
      }
    }
    return $render_state;
  }
}
```

If you like the way, let me know. I can supply for more form input type like select, checkbox, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The approach is correct, as mentioned in the CodeIgniter docs. In fact, you don't need to include the second parameter in set_value.

**set_value definition:**

```
string set_value(string $field = '', string $default = '')

//$field: If there is a submitted field with this name, its value is returned.
//$default: If there is no matching submitted field, this value is returned.
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes,You should.

```
 set_value() is used to re-populate a form has failed validation. 
  There is no additional filtering on it,  so it faster.

 But, I prefer some times to use $this->input->post() for the secure.
```